# How do I properly add files to a Code::Blocks project?

Tags: c++, g++, codeblocks

I made a code blocks(ninja) GLFW project through cmake and it didn't auto generate any main.cpp file for me to start writing the actual program so I had to create it manually. When I added it to the project through the "Add files..." option it seemed to work.

The file did indeed appear in the tree and I was able to open and write to it but when I hit Save and then Build it said "Ninja: no work to do" despite the file changing. When I hit Run it said "It seems that this project has not been built yet. Do you want to build it now?".

Pressing yes, it again said "no work to do." and and the previous window disappeared. However when I navigated to main.cpp in the projects tree right clicked on the file and hit Build file it worked and produced a main.o file and this Build log output:

```
-------------- Build file: all in GLFW (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -m64  -c ~/glfw-3.3.8/glfw-3.3.8/build/main.cpp -o ~/glfw-3.3.8/glfw-3.3.8/build/.objs/build/main.o
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

What am I missing? Why does the build project option not build this file?

I have tried doing this manually through the command prompt through g++ and it worked. I also linked the .o file through g++ into an executable file and it executed flawlessly. What I don't understand is why it won't do this all automatically when I hit Build and run? I know it's capable of this because when I hit compile this file and then added the g++ linking command I used to the post build steps it did indeed link the file into a working executable.

Comment: This is not how CMake it used. You don't modify the projects generated by it. If you need to add a new source file, you add it to the CMakeLists.txt, then have CMake regenerate the project for you.

Comment: That explains it, thanks!